# CMake 3.12 With Vulkan in CLion Issues

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, clion, vulkan

I am trying to link Vulkan correctly in CMake, and I receive an error when I attempt to refresh/build. Here is my `CMakeList.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(game)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(SOURCE_FILES game.cpp window.cpp window.hpp type_definitions.hpp windows_definitions.hpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Vulkan_LIBRARY})
```

However, I receive the following error:

> C:\Users\username.CLion2018.2\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe
>   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /cygdrive/c/Users/username/Projects/Programming/game
>   -- Could NOT find Vulkan (missing: Vulkan_LIBRARY)  CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to
>   NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set and tested
>   correctly in the CMake files: Vulkan_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
>       linked by target "game" in directory /cygdrive/c/Users/username/Projects/Programming/game

So, I have tried to do it manually:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(game)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(SOURCE_FILES game.cpp window.cpp window.hpp type_definitions.hpp windows_definitions.hpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_path(Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES vulkan/vulkan.h PATHS "$ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/Include")
find_library(Vulkan_LIBRARY NAMES "vulkan-1" PATHS "$ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/Lib" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

include_directories(${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Vulkan_LIBRARY})
```

And still get another error...

> C:\Users\username.CLion2018.2\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe
>   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /cygdrive/c/Users/username/Projects/Programming/game CMake Error: The
>   following variables are used in this project, but they are set to
>   NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set and tested
>   correctly in the CMake files: Vulkan_LIBRARY
>       linked by target "game" in directory /cygdrive/c/Users/username/Projects/Programming/game

Now, this baffles me because I have installed the Vulkan SDK and my `VULKAN_SDK` path variable is set correctly. It also seems to gather the include directory correctly, and only fails when trying to get the library. I have also checked in  my file explorer that the `vulkan-1.lib` file exists and is in the path searched by `$ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/Lib`. What could possibly go wrong? Is it something to do with cygwin or my cmake version? I am using c++ (GCC) 7.3.0 from cygwin x64 and cmake 3.12.3 bundled with CLion.

EDIT: This works, but I do not want it to be a permanent solution:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(game)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(SOURCE_FILES game.cpp window.cpp window.hpp type_definitions.hpp windows_definitions.hpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

include_directories("$ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/Include")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "$ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/Lib/vulkan-1.lib")
```

Comment: Could you check content of [CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES.html) variable (via `message()`)? On Windows systems it should contain `.lib`, but I am not sure about cygwin environment. Also, using `PATH $ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/Lib` looks weird (well, it is how it is used in `FindVulkan.cmake` script, but nevertheless). Try to replace the option with two options `PATH ENV VULKAN_SDK PATH_SUFFIXES Lib`, which properly handle Windows path separators.

Comment: The output of `message(${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})` is `.dll.a.a`. I just tried `set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .lib)

find_path(Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES vulkan/vulkan.h PATHS ENV VULKAN_SDK PATH_SUFFIXES Include)
find_library(Vulkan_LIBRARY NAMES vulkan-1 PATHS ENV VULKAN_SDK PATH_SUFFIXES Lib)

include_directories(${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Vulkan_LIBRARY})` and it still didn't work...

Comment: `.dll.a.a` is actually `.dll.a;.a` - a **list** of two values, `.dll.a` and `.a`. (Hint: For output *list variables*, enclose them into double quotes: `message("${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES}")`. Could you repeat the same with [CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES.html) variable? For find *unprefixed* `vulkan-1.lib`, the list variable should contain empty string as one of its values. Something like `;lib`.

Comment: The output is just `lib`, no empty item.

Comment: Okay somehow I got it to work, see my answer. Not sure what happened. Anyways, thanks for taking the time to help, I appreciate.

Comment: So, CMake cygwin environment is similar to MinGW one, which cannot find pure `.lib` libraries using their names... You may either modify (e.g with `list(APPEND)`) `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES` and `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES` variables, so even `find_package(Vulkan)` should work. Or, if you use `find_library` by yourself, you may add **exact** filename to the `NAMES` option: `find_library(Vulkan_LIBRARY NAMES "vulkan-1" "vulkan-1.lib" ...)`.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I tried what I originally had with `find_pacakge` and somehow it worked when it had not previously. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Could you check values of `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES` and `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES` variables in your "working" environment?

Comment: How do I do that? I used `message` in CMakeList and they are the same as before. CLion does everything automatically.

Comment: Strange. Are you sure that your project can be configured **cleanly** (that is, from the build directory which contains nothing)? I doesn't know which CLion's option provides that, but it definitely should exist. It is just for check, that caching is unrelated here (You may have not-working project and set the cache values somehow, then project will work.. but until you delete the cache or move the project sources.)

Comment: So I cloned it to my laptop and tried, and it failed. I am getting strange undefined behavior, as when I do the solution you mentioned first (the custom `find_library`) it works. Then, when I change it to `find_package` after that it works miraculously, even after restarting computer and CLion. However, `find_package` does not work if I had not done it manually first. Very strange, and when I print the suffix and prefix variables for the working `find_package` version they still do not include `.lib` and the blank prefix, so I'm not sure what to say.

Comment: Once `find_library` succeeds, it stores result variable in the cache. So futher `find_library` doesn't search actually, but takes the path from the cache. Because `FindVulkan.cmake` script (used by `find_package(Vulkan)`) also uses `find_library` with the same variable, it takes that variable from the cache too. So everything looks nice.. but until the cache is cleared.

Comment: Strange. Any idea how to solve it legit?